# PDO gives empty array

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to make requests and get the responds from databases using PDO but it always throws back empty array.

---

#### My code :

- [**index.html**](http://pastebin.com/SwhUWSCa)
- [**pdo_connect.php**](http://pastebin.com/dFikHDRD)

Comment: Add oyur code here not as link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please do not use this function, it is wrong in so many aspects.

If you want to keep up with this kind of function, make it at least this way

```
function dataQuery($query, $params = array())
{
    static $dbh;

    if (!$dbh)
    {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', USER, PASS);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

And then use it as this

```
function pleaseWork() {
    return dataQuery("SELECT * FROM `grupy`")->fetchAll();
}

$work = pleaseWork();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($work);
```

note that when there are no parameters are to be used in the query, you don't have to provide them as well.

Comment: It works now, but it cant get the utf-8 chars, how can I manage to get them?

Comment: And how can I now transform this in to the javascript variable and console log this? I tried many ways from this board and it never works.

Comment: use json_encode or better ask another question how to send PHP data to JS as this topic has been moved too far away already

Comment: So talking about this thread. Why does this code doubles the variables? Like that: [screenshot](http://s29.postimg.org/tnd1suqjb/screenshot_1769.png)

Comment: bacause of the default PDO behavior. you may override it either directly in the call, `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` or globally (preferred), by setting `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as the connection option

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why the query wont work, except what is 'SELECT'? Remove:

```
&& 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]
```

From

```
if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
```

Comment: Removed, still same thing happens.